# Aligning a resized TextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

I am having problem aligning a resized `TextField` in `Jetpack Compose` for Desktop. When I resize the width of the `TextField`, the `TextField` automatically adjust itself to center position on screen. I have tried using `Modify.Align` and it did not work.

Can someone help? Here is my code

```
@Composable
fun addSales(sales: Sales,
             actionChangeSales: (sales: Sales) -> Unit,
             actionQuantityInc: (() -> Unit),
             actionItemNameInc: (() -> Unit)){
    Column{
        TextField(
            value = sales.itemName,
            textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.DarkGray),
            onValueChange = {
                actionChangeSales(Sales(itemName = it))
                actionItemNameInc.invoke()
            },
            label = { Text("Item name")}
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = roundQuantity(sales.quantitySold),
            textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.DarkGray),
            onValueChange = {
                actionChangeSales(Sales(quantitySold = getDoubleFromEditText(it)))
                actionQuantityInc.invoke()
            },
            label = { Text("Quantity")},
            modifier = Modifier.width(120.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please ignore the **Sales object** and **actions** parsed as arguments in the **function**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, try to wrap *OutlinedTextField* with *Box* and apply the *width* modifier there:

```kotlin
            Box(modifier = Modifier.width(120.dp)) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = "123456789",
                    textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.DarkGray),
                    onValueChange = {},
                    label = { Text("Quantity") },
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap them in a `Column` again.

Pseudo code as below

```
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifiler.fillMaxWidth() // needed so it knows the full width to center the content within it
) {
    // This wraps your content and centers it
    
    Column( horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start ){
        // This wraps and aligns the content to the left/start

        // place your content here
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't pass `horizontalArrangement` as an argument in `Column()`. Working with compose for Desktop

Comment: seems like desktop is (still?) using `horizontalAlignment`

I'll update the answer to match.

https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/fbba7e79c59593c4196b7da38d0eba82b1f836e1/examples/todoapp/common/compose-ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/example/todo/common/ui/TodoEditUi.kt#L29